# Python/Tensorflow: Saver for network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

According to the documentation and numerous SO posts regarding this API, the saver object must be created using

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(...variables...)
```

I wanted to know if there is any way to automatically populate the `(...variables...)` without having to explicitly list all variables and ops used in my network.

Right now my network is only two layers so it is not a huge hassle, but it feels downright stone-age like to have to list all the variables manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default initializer for `tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/saving_and_restoring_variables#Saver.__init__) will create an instance that saves/restores all saveable objects in your graph, which typically includes all of your model variables. Therefore you should be able to write:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

…and get the desired effect without too much trouble.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to restore it now using the following code: `with tf.Session() as sess: \ new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("model-path.meta") \ new_saver.restore(sess, "model-path") \ print(tf.get_collection('vars'))`

But tf.get_collection('vars') returns an empty array. Is there something wrong with how I am trying to restore it?

Comment: Note that `tf.get_collection('vars')` will probably return an empty list, unless you've deliberately added some variables to a collection with that name. Did you perhaps mean `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)` (which is the default collection for most variables, unless you specify otherwise)?